# VS code unable to create new cell while using iJAVA that is build on jshell?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-python, ijavascript

I am just a beginner :) 
 Can any one help me out??

When I click the plus sign to create a new cell in a workbook I get an error. The new cell isn't created and I see this error message in a larger than usual font.

The error message survives a restart of the kernel.

The error is gone after I restart VSCode.

The error is also gone after I save / close the file and re-open it.

**code**

> System.out.print("hello jshell");

and then i hit **alt + enter**

**output**

> hello jshell

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined at 

in t
in div
in t
in div
in t
in div
in t
in div
in div
in div
in div
in div
in div
in t
in h
in t
in div
in div
in div
in t
in main
in div
in t
in h
in f
```

I am using

- VS-code version : 1.51.1
- jupyter core    : 4.6.3
- jupyter-notebook : 6.1.5
- qtconsole        : 4.7.7
- ipython          : 7.18.1
- ipykernel        : 5.3.4
- jupyter client   : 6.1.7
- jshell           : 15.0.1

[out put screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTb2j.jpg)

Comment: where's the `in t in div in t in div` from? can you post all code. when you open a new jupyter notebook and code in it ,does this error show again?

Comment: @MollyWang yes its the error is same even in new notebook.(only if done with ijava and vscode) **in t in div in t in div f** appeared instead of new cell, in place of new cell

Comment: I reproduced your issue and i'm finding solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've added the java to Jupyter Kernel and with many tests conducted, it's an issue in VS Code:

[image: Error in VS Code]

There're [many similar issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/893) posted in GitHub and now, this function is solved in [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) but still not in VS Code:

[image: Run well in VS Code Insiders]

You can install VS Code Insider, but it may not that stable, after all it's the beta-version of VS Code. In another way, you can turn to [JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/), try it in browser or install it.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, I think it'll be solved in near future and you can keep using VS Code to develop projects :)